# Ошибка: "Форма указанной строки не годится для адреса электронной почты."

Tags: c#, .net

Ошибка возникает при инициализации объекта MailAddress, используя строку вида: "exeсutive@do-men.ru". На мой взгляд, проблема может быть только в использовании символа '-' в домене адреса. И поскольку все поля этого объекта стринговые, ошибка именно в парсере конструктора. Единственное, что приходит в голову, - проинициализировать этот объект вручную, но у него все поля не имеют сеттера. Отказаться от именно этого объекта не получится, т.к. использую его для указания полей "From" и "To" объекта MailMessage.
У кого какие мысли?

Comment: Надо больше информации, поскольку код вида `var address = new MailAddress("exeсutive@do-men.ru");` создает валидный объект `MailAddress` без каких-либо ошибок или исключений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, разобрался. Клиент указал в своём адресе адресе русскую букву "c"=)))